# Independence of $X$ and $Y$ implies independence of $X^2$ and $Y$

Tags: random-variables, independence

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. Prove that $X^2$ and $Y$ are also independent.

I saw this question was asked but never explicitly solved so was wondering if this was the correct strategy:
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent there joint distribution is $F(X, Y)$ and can be written as
$$F(X, Y) = F_X(x)F_Y(y) \implies P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(X \leq x)P(Y \leq y)$$
Now, let $g(x) = X^2 \text{ and } h(y) = y$
Then:
$$F_{g(x), g(y)}(x, y) = P(g(x) \leq x, h(y) \leq y)$$
$$= P(x \in g^{-1}(0, x], y \in h^{-1}(0, h])$$
$$= P(x \in g^{-1}(0, x])P(y \in h^{-1}(0, h])$$
$$= P(g(x) \leq x)P(h(y) \leq y)$$
$$= F_{g(x)}(x)F_{h(y)}(y) = F_{X^2}F_{Y}(y) $$

Comment: It can be done in general: Say $X,Y$ are independent. By definition it means $\sigma(X),\sigma(Y)$ are independent $\sigma-$fields. Note that for any $\mathcal F \subset \sigma(X)$, $\mathcal G \subset \sigma(Y)$ we have that $\mathcal F, \mathcal G$ are independent (trivial by definition). Take any borel functions $g,h$ (in your example $g(x) = x^2, h(x) = x$). We have that $\sigma(g \circ X) \subset \sigma(X)$ and similarly $\sigma(h \circ Y) \subset \sigma(Y)$, (again, look at definition of sigma field generated by random variable). Hence $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are independent.

Comment: @Manny Please try to make your titles more descriptive (and try not to break up your question between the title and the body either). There's an infinite universe of problems that start with with "let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be Borel sets in $\mathbb R$. Let $C=\{x: x^{2} \in A\}$. $P(X^{2} \in A, Y \in B)=P(X \in C,Y \in B)=P(X \in C) P(Y \in B)=P(X^{2} \in A)P( Y \in B)$. [$C$is  a Borel set becaushe  the map $x  \to x^{2}$ is continuous and hence Borel measurable].